# Connection to "process /usr/sbin/sendmail -bs" has been closed unexpectedly

Tags: laravel, sendmail, laravel-9

I have updated my Laravel version 5.4 to version 9. After that, the project is working fine, apart from sending emails.

> Connection to "process /usr/bin/sendmail -bs" has been closed
> unexpectedly

Comment: Hi Anand! Have you solved that issue? Because I am experiencing the same...

Comment: Laravel used to use the built-in mail function to send email, but now in version 9, it uses the SwiftMailer library.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at https://talk.plesk.com/threads/removal-of-bs-option-from-plesk-sendmail-wrapper.365077/

As long as the plesk guys aren't able to deliver a stable interface to their  sendmail binary, you can fiddle around with command line options that will stop working without any notice. Or probably you'll better use native PHP transport (https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/mailer.html#using-built-in-transports).